# Usual combinations of nouns/verbs and prepositions

Tags: prepositions, nouns, resources, online-resources

Following [Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/list_1), we can find out that word **list** can be used together with the preposition **of** (example sentence: A list of the world’s richest people).

We are looking for a collection in reverse form. That is a list of common words associated with a specific preposition (e.g., **of**) to the left. So far, we've created [this collection](https://temos.ccmi.fit.cvut.cz/sources).

Do you know of a resource that meets this form?

Comment: Just look for the collocates in a large corpus. Are you interested in words to the left or to the right of “of”? Are you familiar with collocation measurements?

Comment: We are interested in words to the left of preposition (question updated). Yes, collocates sound like the right way, thanks! I ask because I don't want to skip already existing resources.

Comment: Yo could go to https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/ . The Corpus of Contemporary American English. Type in [nn*] of. That will give you combinations of any noun followed by of in order of frequency. By default it’ll show the top 100, but you can change to as many as you like under the options. But be careful - that’ll give you more examples than a human can handle manually.

Comment: That's a great source, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure!

The one that suits your needs is the Collocation Dictionary from [ProWritingAid](https://prowritingaid.com/Free-Online-Collocations-Dictionary.aspx).

Comment: Thanks! The one from [ProWritingAid](https://prowritingaid.com/en/Collocation/Dictionary/?word=of) meets our requirement of "inverse way". Based on the query (word **of**), we can get the common noun collocations.

The [Collocation Dictionary](http://www.freecollocation.com) and [Ozdic](http://www.ozdic.com/collocation-dictionary/grudge) do not accept the preposition (e.g., **of**) as a query.

Comment: @David Thanks; I'll edit to suit your needs.